# "fatal error, no screen found" when installing 12.04 with live USB

Tags: installation, xorg, graphics, dell, dell-vostro

I have downloaded 12.04 and made a bootable USB flash drive. Then I installed this version on my laptop (Dell Vostro 1510).

Unfortunately my laptop does not run with Ubuntu. Actually just after the appearance of the Ubuntu logo the display disappears. When I try to run commands through the command line it does not work neither and the error is the following: `fatal error, no screen found`. I should mention that the laptop works properly with the bootable USB flash.

Please let me know if there is a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen due to bad USB bootable flash. Recreate your flash with [this](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/), if you are a Windows user. If you are a Linux user, you can use [this](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/usb-creator). Then try the installation again.